# Python Pandas delete every row after specific value in cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks as follows:

```
    streak 
0      1.0 
1      2.0 
2      0.0 
3      1.0 
4      2.0 
5      0.0 
6      0.0
```

I want to delete every row after the first `0.0` in the `streak` column.

The result should look like this:

```
    streak 
0      1.0 
1      2.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get index of first `0` by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and slice by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html), only need default unique indices:

```
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.iloc[:df['streak'].eq(0).idxmax()]
print (df)
   streak
0     1.0
1     2.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['streak'].eq(0).idxmax())
2
```

EDIT: For more general solution is necessary use `numpy` - get position by [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
print (df)
   streak
a     1.0
b     2.0
c     0.0
d     1.0
e     2.0
f     0.0
g     0.0

df = df.iloc[:df['streak'].eq(0).values.argmax()]
print (df)
   streak
a     1.0
b     2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalized solution via `numpy.where`. It will work for matching first instance of any specified value.

```
df = df.iloc[:np.where(df['streak']==0)[0][0]]

#    streak
# 0     1.0
# 1     2.0
```